# How to get rails to render in json a bigdecimal as a number without a trailing zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I would like to know how to get rails to render in json a bigdecimal as a number without a trailing zero.

Currently in my app, using `as_json` Rails renders a bigdecimal value of an active record entity as a number with a decimal, e.g. bigdecimal 2.0 is rendered 2.0 (not a string). I want it to be rendered as 2 (not a string, without trailing zero).

To attempt this, I have made use of jbuilder and used the rails helper method `number_with_precision` and option `strip_insignificant_zeros: true`; however, this converts the value to a string. Tacking on `to_f` to the end makes '2' 2.0.

Is there a way to render in json a bigdecimal as a number without trailing zeros?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fractional part of the number is 0 - just convert to Integer, otherwise convert to Float.

```
(x.frac.zero? ? x.to_i : x.to_f)
```